# df.to_html() shows in flask html source code, but not a browser's interpretation of that code. How to fix?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I hope it will be easy but I cannot render a Dataframe.to_html() in flask. How to do it?
It renders me a code on my webpage but not a table. Screenshot is below.
I have a dictionary. Key is df_html and value is a html code from pandas DataFrame:

```
results = {
"df_html": df.to_html(index=False, classes='table table-stripped', header=True, escape=False) 
}
```

Then I render it in my route method like this:

```
return render_template("results.html", results_dict=results)
```

then in results.html I have this code (jinja, flask):

```
{% for table in results_dict.df_html %}
 {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

An it outputs to me a html code (source code). How to fix it and make it show a normal html table? Should I add some tags around jinja-flask code?
Update: For some reason each symbol is spaced in this html code generated by pandas
Image Link: https://tinypic.host/i/DIlab

Comment: ok I've found a solution. Just not to loop and use this code in html {{ results_dict.df_html|safe }}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `for` loop.  `df.to_html` returns a single string, not a list of strings.  So, what you're doing there is iterating through that string character by character.  Replace that whole thing with:

```
{{ results_dict.df_html }}
```